# How to Add Columns from DataTable to ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, dataset, datacolumn

I have a `ComboBox` and a `DataSet`. I want to add each `DataColumn` to `ComboBox` as `ComboBox Item`.
I have tried this code:

```
DataColumn[] column_collection=new DataColumn[dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
dataset.Tables[0].Columns.CopyTo(column_collection, 0);
combo_box.Items.AddRange(column_collection);
```

However, problem is that I just get a Empty List when I open `ComboBox`. That list has same number of items as there are columns, however there is no Value in it.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
var columns = dataset.Tables[0].Columns
              .OfType<DataColumn>()
              .Select(c => c.ColumnName);

combo_box.Items.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. `System.Data.DataTable` does not contain a definition for `OfType` and no extension method `OfType` accepting a first argument of type `System.Data.DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
combo_box.Items.AddRange(column_collection);
```

Write this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < column_collection.Length;i++)
    {
        combo_box.Items.Add(column_collection.GetValue(i).ToString());
    }
```